# getting an Exception in VB.net while injecting target with source using Value Injector

Tags: .net, vb.net, mapper, valueinjecter

I am getting this exception. "Public member `InjectFrom` on type `ApplicationObj_B` not found."

I figured out the reason for this. This is because, I am checking if the source property type is value or array only. However, my source property type is an object which has properties inside it. How to write that thrid condition and inject values of those properties inside that object?

I am trying to inject one object and its child object to target object and child object. It has basically properties. Please help me

It throws exception in the final Create Activator instance line.

```
 Protected Overrides Function SetValue(c As ConventionInfo) As Object
            If c.SourceProp.Type.IsValueType OrElse c.SourceProp.Type = GetType(String) OrElse c.TargetProp.Type.IsValueType OrElse c.TargetProp.Type = GetType(String) Then
                Return c.SourceProp.Value
            End If

        If c.SourceProp.Type.IsArray Then
            Dim arr = TryCast(c.SourceProp.Value, Array)
            If arr IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim clone = TryCast(Activator.CreateInstance(c.TargetProp.Type, arr.Length), Array)

                For index As Integer = 0 To arr.Length - 1
                    Dim a = arr.GetValue(index)
                    If a.[GetType]().IsValueType OrElse TypeOf a Is String Then
                        Continue For
                    End If
                    If clone IsNot Nothing Then
                        clone.SetValue(Activator.CreateInstance(c.TargetProp.Type.GetElementType()).InjectFrom(Of CloneInjection)(a), index)
                    End If
                Next
                Return clone
            End If
        End If

        Return Activator.CreateInstance(c.TargetProp.Type).InjectFrom(Of CloneInjection)(c.SourceProp.Value)
    End Function
```

Comment: And we're suppose to help you having no idea what the code is?

Comment: @AlexJolig: I apologize, I was writing the code now editing it. Sorry

Comment: Ok, It throws what exception exactly?

Comment: Public member InjectFrom on type 'Childnot 'found. On debugging I find that I don't see a value on TargetType

Comment: sorry it says "Not found"

Comment: You really need to update your question with the exact information about the exception you get

Comment: @AlexJolig: I found the reason by debugging. It is because, it is neither array or value but an object of type B. So I may potentially have to write a condition for if it is a class then inject those property value of that class. How to do that please? I am new, please help me

Comment: @AlexJolig: Updated my question